# Tkinter widgets in frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I have a `LabelFrame` that has `columnspan` of 3. I would like the 2 `Checkbutton` widgets in the frame to be on either side. How can I grid the widgets accordingly?

I tried doing `sticky='e'` and `sticky='w'` but it is not doing what I want it to.

```py
frame = tk.LabelFrame(window, text='Tools', font=('Helvetica', 15), fg='white',
                                        bg='#022340')
frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew', columnspan=3)

button1 = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text='Button1', font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'),bg='red')
button2 = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text='Button2', font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'),bg='yellow')

button1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
button2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
```

This is what I'm looking for:
[image: Format that I want]

Comment: The buttons appear to be on the sides. What is the problem/question?

Comment: @APhillips That is how I want it to appear. Not how it actually is. Right now it is appearing side by side on the left of the frame

Comment: Try adding `frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have placed a `Label` widget with some width and no text `in between` the two checkbuttons and gave it the same background as that of the root window.

I have used the `grid_rowconfigure()` and `grid_columnconfigure()` for the `window` and the `frame` to make the GUI responsive.

I have added a `Label` widget at the bottom of the GUI so that you can have an idea of how to add widgets below it if your app has more than the two checkbutton widgets.

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.LabelFrame(window, text='Tools', font=('Helvetica', 15), fg='white', bg='#022340')
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame.grid_rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure((1), weight=1)

button1 = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text='Button1', font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'), bg='red')
button2 = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text='Button2', font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'), bg='yellow')

# the label widget between the two checkbuttons
label_m = tk.Label(frame, width=30, bg='#022340')
label_m.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Add some padding to separate them apart
button1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')
button2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

# a label widget to show how all widgets are placed in GUI
label = tk.Label(frame, text='A Label Widget', bg='white')
label.grid(row=1, sticky='nswe', columnspan=3)

window.mainloop()
```

**Screenshots**

[image: g1]

[image: g2]

[image: g3]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But will the padding adjust to window size change? Or stay fixed in the specified padding amount.

Comment: It also seems to mess with spacing of other frames that I have in the UI for some reason

Comment: Hey @RachelRaikar, I have updated the code that now will make the GUI responsive. Please check the updated code and let me know in the comments if this is still not answering your question.